# What language did Petlura speak casually?

Tags: language, ukraine

In Bulgakov's novel ["The White Guard"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Guard) one of the characters, Turbin alleges that [Simon Petlura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symon_Petliura) does not speak Ukrainian language himself despite the measures he took to promote it.

Are there any historical sources about what language Petlura in fact preferred to speak?

Comment: The wikipedia page says that Petlura was educated to join the Orthodox Russian clergy and published in Russian and Ukrainian; I'd assume that Turbin was asserting that Petlura preferred Russian to Ukrainian.

Answer (score 8):

Given that he was [born to a Cossack family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symon_Petliura#Life_before_the_Revolution), and one of his first jobs out of school was helping a library organize its [Kuban Cossack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuban_Cossacks) material, my money would be on [Balachka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balachka).

Technically that may just be a dialect of Ukrainian, but that distinction gets kind of muddy (specifically *political*) in Europe. Given some of his known writings, he certainly did know Ukrainian. This could have just been an incident of someone being snobby about his Balachka accent.

As near as I can tell, the concept of Little Russia (essentially Ukrainians being nothing more than an off flavor of Russians, rather than their own people) was a bit of a political marker at the time. In Czarist times, it was a popular viewpoint, but after the revolution that view became discouraged. So it could well be that this particular dismissive attitude toward the local languages/dialects was meant to tell you where on the political spectrum the character Turbin lay.

Comment: Bulgakov isn't known for either chauvinism or being dismissive of other slavic cultures.

Comment: @DVK - Yeah, the more I read up on this, the more I'm thinking the writer quite likely did this with a character of his on purpose.